# How to format only one section of RMarkdown pdf output using sectsy

Tags: markdown, sectsty

I am creating a pdf using R-markdown. I want ALL section headings to be centered (using sectsty package),except the  first one which should be left aligned. How can I do this ? How do I use sectsty for only one section ?

Here is a minimal working example :

```
---
date : 2018-April-25
output:
    pdf_document:
toc: true
toc_depth: 1
title: "Test document"
fontsize: 12pt

header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{sectsty} \allsectionsfont{\centering}
---


\sectionfont{\left}

## This is a heading

## This is a second heading.
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: There is no `\left` command (well there is, but it doesn't do what you think it does). Just use `\sectionfont{}`

Answer (score 3):

What you tried didn't work because the `\left` macro is a mathmode macro for making an extensible left delimiter. Your document should have generated an error if compiled, but maybe it gets hidden from you.

Try the following:

```
---
title: "secsty-test"
date: "4/25/2018"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{sectsty} \allsectionsfont{\centering}
---
\allsectionsfont{\raggedright}
## This is a heading

\allsectionsfont{\centering}
## This is a second heading.
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: When I do \sectionfont{} in place of \sectionfont{\left} it makes no difference. When I remove the empty line between \sectionfont{} and the first heading it DOES left align the first heading, but the second heading is bold and the first one is not. Also it displays the ## before the first heading. How can I make the first and second heading exactly the same except for the left alignment?

Comment: @user2338823 Sorry I tested with a LaTeX document not an `Rmd` document.  I've updated with a sample `Rmd`. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. Query : can I not modify only  ONE section using sectionfont ? Must I modify all future sections ?

Comment: @user2338823 I don't think so.

Comment: Then what is the difference between sectionfont and allsectionsfont ?

Comment: @user2338823 These commands work as you would expect in a LaTeX document. It's the conversion from markdown that makes them behave differently but I have no idea why.